# Redux createStore<StoreState> produces an error: Expected 4 type arguments, but got 1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, redux, react-redux

I am following a [TypeScript-React-Starter tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter), and creating a store in `src/index.tsx`. From the tutorial,

```
const store = createStore<StoreState>(enthusiasm, {
  enthusiasmLevel: 1,
  languageName: 'I\'m fluent in Math and Klingon'
});
```

produces the error

```
Expected 4 type arguments, but got 1.
```

[Issue #136](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter/issues/136) suggests using

```
import { EnthusiasmAction } from './actions/index';

const store = createStore<StoreState, EnthusiasmAction, any, any>(enthusiasm, {
  enthusiasmLevel: 1,
  languageName: 'I\'m fluent in Math and Klingon'
});
```

among other similar solutions, but that produces another error:

```
Argument of type '(state: StoreState, action: EnthusiasmAction) => StoreState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<StoreState, EnthusiasmAction>'.
Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
  Type 'StoreState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'StoreState'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'StoreState'.
```

The issue is closed, but other people have had the same problem since.

**How do I create my store?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> const store = createStore<StoreState>(enthusiasm, {
>   enthusiasmLevel: 1,
>   languageName: 'I\'m fluent in Math and Klingon'
> });
> ```
>
> produces the error
>
> ```
> Expected 4 type arguments, but got 1.
> ```

This was due to the tutorial using Redux 3.7.2 while I was using Redux 4.0.1.

**Solution #1**

I installed Redux 3.7.2:

```
npm install redux@3.7.2
```

Since I was using the [TypeScript-React-Starter tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter), this was the solution that worked best with the tutorial.

**Solution #2**

I altered the createStore() function to take 4 type arguments as the error message suggested:

```
const store = createStore<StoreState, Action<any>, unknown, unknown>(enthusiasm, {
  enthusiasmLevel: 1,
  languageName: 'I\'m fluent in Math and Klingon',
});
```

Now I can continue the [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter) using Redux 4.0.1. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating initial state in the reducer instead while creating the store. It should work.

```
export interface IStoreState {
    languageName: string;
    enthusiasmLevel: number
}
```

```
const initState: IStoreState = {
    languageName: "TypeScript",
    enthusiasmLevel: 0
}
```